# PHP Post data not sending

Tags: php

I have an external class that asks for input and returns the input back to the original page.  I have the same setup working on other modules, but it won't work on this one.  I have tried renaming the submit name and adding an action page to the form, but have had no luck.

```
<!-- BanPlayer -->
<div class="modal fade" id="BanPlayerModule" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <form method="POST">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title, text-danger" id="myModalLabel">Ban <?php echo $Username; ?></h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <table style='padding:0px; margin:0px;' class='table table-condensed'>
                        <thead>
                            <th>Player</th><th>Length</th><th>Reason</th>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr><td><?php echo $Username; ?></td><td><input name="BanTime" placeholder="10d4h30s" type="text"></td><td><input type="text" name="BanReason" placeholder="Was impersonating an admin"></td></tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                    <button type="submit" name="banPlayer" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Ban</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- End BanPlayer Modal -->
```

Other Class

```
<?php
        //ban player
        if(isset($_POST['banPlayer'])) {
            echo 'yay';
    ?>
```

Comment: Maybe try adding an `action="/path"` to your form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In which page your php code is written? Suppose if it is on test.php then in the html replace the form with

```
<form method="POST" action="test.php">
```

If it is in the same page then write

```
<form method="POST" action="#">
```